# Are attributes and properties with dashes supported in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I can make a [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) checkbox using the following html:

```
<polymer-element name="role-checkbox1" attributes="ariachecked" on-click="{{clickHandler}}">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host::after {
                font-size: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                content: '+';
                width: 1em;
                height: 1em;
            }
            :host[ariachecked]::after {
                content: 'x';
            }
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('role-checkbox1', {
        ariachecked: false,
        clickHandler: function() {
            this.ariachecked = !this.ariachecked;
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The following is the exact same except that *ariachecked* is now *aria-checked* and the *role-checkbox1* is not role-checkbox2.  This does not seem to be working.  Is there a way that I can use the *aria-checked* attribute?  Can I bind this attribute to another named property?

```
<polymer-element name="role-checkbox2" attributes="aria-checked" on-click="{{clickHandler}}">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host::after {
                font-size: 100px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                content: '+';
                width: 1em;
                height: 1em;
            }
            :host[aria-checked]::after {
                content: 'x';
            }
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('role-checkbox2', {
        'aria-checked': false,
        clickHandler: function() {
            this['aria-checked'] = !this['aria-checked'];
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/kosik/1/edit?html,output) (Click on the two boxes, only the left one is working)

Answer (score 3):

Currently converting dashed attributes to camel case is not supported.
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/193#issuecomment-40162114

Looks like you found the Github thread on this already :)

I'm thinking you'll need to do something kind of like this:

```
<polymer-element name="role-checkbox1" attributes="checked" on-click="{{clickHandler}}">
  <template>
    :host[checked]::after {
      content:'x';
    }
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('role-checkbox1', {
    checked: false,
    clickHandler: function() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
      this.setAttribute('aria-checked', this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

http://jsbin.com/dukeq/3/edit

Comment: I'm not even trying to use camel case. In trying to use the properties with dashes.

Answer (score 1):

With polymer 1.0, it is now the default behavior to convert dashed attributes to camelCased properties.